# How to see the elements of IEnumerable while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am using an IEnumerable and in the debugger I would like to see the items that it has, but I can't because there is not any property neither items.

Is it possible to see the items that has the IEnumerable?

Comment: hover your mouse on that variable, expand the ResultView ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "local" window and expand the Results View.

Answer (score 8):

By doing what this instructs you to do:

[image]

I.e. click on those circular arrows on the left of the highlighted area.

Answer (score 5):

While debugging, set a break point then in VS go to:

`Debug -> Windows -> Immediate`  then in Immediate window type these commands:

```
yourEnumerable.ToList()
yourEnumerable.Count() // see how many elements are in
yourEnumerable.ToList()[0] // access by index
yourEnumerable.ToArray()[0] // also access by index
```

Comment: The local window is great, but I like this answer because when you use the immediate window, the window retains your results after the debug session.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to expanding the results view, you can, in the watch window, use the "results" [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx).

For example, if the enumerable variable is named "myIEnumerable", type "myIEnumerable, results" into the name column of the watch window.

The minor benefit of the results specifier over expanding the results view is that it avoids showing the various enumerator properties, thus preserving screen real estate for the results.

Answer (score 2):

there are dozens of possibilities for that.
you could try

```
 .ToList();
 // and access single elements through the index
 .ToList()[0];
 //you can use type those commands in the table at
 //"observe local"
```

[image: use "observe local" in VS]

Answer (score 1):

In `Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition`, the debugger shows the resultset according to the effective datatype:

[image]

It makes no difference if you are hovering over the interface-typed variable or the original collection variable.